# Find position given distance from known points

Tags: javascript

Before someone points me to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472548/finding-position-of-a-point-in-cartesian-coordinate-by-knowing-its-distance-from), I have seen that but can't read it (I wish I could). I'm looking for a simple way (as I'm not very good at math) or someone that can translate that into JavaScript.

Basically, I want to find the coordinates of a point, given 3 or more points (can be 20) and given the distance between the point i'm looking for and the given points. How can I start on this?

Ideally, I'd like to obtain something like

```
function getPoint(array){
    var pt = {x:0, y:0};
    //the hot stuff here that I need help with
    return pt;
}

var a = [{x:10, y:10, d:30}, {x:10, y:50, d:20} ...];
getPoint(a);
```

I was thinking about calculating circle to circle intersection but that would give me back 2 points, so I'm not sure I can find which one.

Comment: Take any 3 different points and draw 3 circles: they would intersect in a single point. And, yes: triangulation.

Comment: Oh so I guess I don't need more than 3..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a centroid algorithm I *think* you can use for this (i might be mistaken!). it will find the center of those points. i added canvas so you can see the points. The red dot one is the center of those (dah).

```js
var c = document.getElementById("c");
var context=c.getContext("2d");

var a = [{x:20, y:10, d:30}, {x:15, y:80, d:20}, {x:80, y:60, d:20}];
console.log(getPoint(a));

function getPoint(points) {

 var cx = 0, cy = 0,
  sa = 0, a, i = 1,
  len = points.length,
        pt1 = points[0], pt2;

    context.fillRect(pt1.x,pt1.y,4,4);
  
 for (; i < len; i++) {

  pt2 = points[i];

  a = pt1.x * pt2.y - pt2.x * pt1.y;
  sa += a;
  cx += (pt1.x + pt2.x) * a;
  cy += (pt1.y + pt2.y) * a;

        context.fillRect(pt1.x,pt1.y,4,4);
      
        pt1 = pt2;
 }

    context.fillRect(pt2.x,pt2.y,4,4);

 sa *= 0.5;
 cx /= (6.0 * sa);
 cy /= (6.0 * sa);

    context.fillStyle="red";
    context.fillRect(cx,cy,4,4);

 return {
  x: cx,
  y: cy
 };
};
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="100" height="100" style="border:2px solid red"></canvas>
```

Comment: Neat, I'll try this out and let you know :)

Comment: Seems to work in some cases, fails in others, not sure what's going on since I don't understand all of that.. I'll validate anyway but would you mind explaining your code a bit please?